# How can i resolve Unknown property 'accounts' referenced in error?

Tags: visualforce, class, dynamic

I have created controller and visual force pages. In my controller using field sets it's working fine. My VF pages having problem for unknown property. What should I need to change in my Visual force page and controller. I mention below error line in my VF page.

```
public with sharing class PageBlockTableFieldSetExample {
    public List<Account> accounts { get; private set; }
    public List<String> headers { get; private set; }
    public List<RowExample> rows { get; private set; }
    //public string accounts1{get;set;}

    public PageBlockTableFieldSetExample() {
        String queryFields = '';
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.Example_Fieldset.getFields()) {
            if(queryFields.length() > 0) {
                queryFields += ', ';
            }
            queryFields += f.getFieldPath();
        }

        //Query the records you want to display
        this.accounts = Database.query(
            ' SELECT ' +
                queryFields +
            ' FROM ' +
                ' Account ' +
            ' WHERE ' +
                ' AccountNumber = null ' +
            ' LIMIT 10 ');


        //Setup the row of classes example
        this.headers = new List<String> { 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday' };
        this.rows = new List<RowExample>();
        for(Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            this.rows.add(new RowExample(this.headers.size()));
        }
    }

    public class RowExample {
        //A variable number of cells in different rows will result in 
        public final List<String> cells { get; private set; }

        public RowExample(Integer length) {
            this.cells = new List<String>();
            for(Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                this.cells.add('Cell ' + (math.random() * 10).intValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page>
<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock id="block">
    <apex:pageBlockTable id="table" var="account" value="{!accounts}">//error Line
        <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" value="{!account.Name}" />
        <apex:repeat var="f" value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.Example_Fieldset}">
            <apex:column headerValue="{!f.label}">
                <apex:inputField value="{!account[f]}" />
            </apex:column>
        </apex:repeat>
   </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the controller in your page.

In your visualforce page, include the controller in the apex:page

```
<apex:page controller="PageBlockTableFieldSetExample" >
```

UPDATE :

for the SOQL error you mentioned in the comment, it seems the final SOQL generated is not having proper syntax. my guess is its having an additional comma in the list of fields before FROM.

if that's the case you can remove the extra comma after the last field using below code before you use it in the Database.Query method

```
if(queryFields.endsWith(','))
  queryFields = queryFields.removeEnd(',');
```

TIP : whenever you see such errors, you should use proper exception handling and debug statements to log your variables and any exceptions to see what's causing the error.

also, [here's a reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fieldsets_describe.htm#FieldSetsDescribeExample) on how to use fieldsets in dynamic SOQL

Comment: @ Vamsi Krishna. Thanks for your response I really want to say sorry for forget create controller..

Comment: now I am getting this error:System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'FROM'

Class.streamingAPI.PageBlockTableFieldSetExample.<init>: line 17, column 1

Comment: Use `System.debug();` to output and debug the query string you're passing to `Database.query();`.  It may be that `queryFields` is blank so you're just passing `SELECT  FROM [...]`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't able to comment on above question so posting as an answer

You need to remove last ", " to be added from below line

> queryFields += ', ';

Otherwise if your queryFields contains id and name than your query become

> select id, name, from Account where accountnumber = null limit 10

Comment: I initially thought that too, but it's adding `queryFields += ', ';` *before* the field name if the string already contains a field name.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly place it.. please check my query:this.accounts = Database.query('SELECT '+ queryFields += ', '; +'FROM ' + ' Account ' + ' WHERE ' + ' AccountNumber = null ' + ' LIMIT 10 ');

Comment: may be you can update your code as below

Comment: @Ritesh Gupta again having query problem. What do I need to change my query.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated few lines in the code as below

```
 String queryFields = '';
    boolean flag = false;
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.Example_Fieldset.getFields()) {
        if(flag){
            queryFields += ', ' + f.getFieldPath();
        }
        else{
            queryFields += f.getFieldPath();
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    if(queryFields != ''){
        //Query the records you want to display
        this.accounts = Database.query(
            ' SELECT ' +
                queryFields +
            ' FROM ' +
                ' Account ' +
            ' WHERE ' +
                ' AccountNumber = null ' +
            ' LIMIT 10 ');
    }

    //Setup the row of classes example
    this.headers = new List<String> { 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday' };
    this.rows = new List<RowExample>();
    for(Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        this.rows.add(new RowExample(this.headers.size()));
    }
```

If the above code didn't show any account than you may not have added any field in mentioned field set.